# Banishing the Command Prompt Window (WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem over here. You see, I wanted to create my own sample application in C# but without Visual Studio creating the files automatically for me. So I figured that I'd simply select "Empty Project" and then create the Program.cs file myself, and then manually add a Windows Form from the Project menu. That went good.

But then when I clicked the Debug button, to my surprise; The console Window sits behind my Applications Window. And if I try to close the console window, it closes my program's window, too. (This is NOT a Console-based application.)

Can somebody please help me get rid of this console window?

I've looked all over the place but have found **nothing** regarding this matter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go into the properties of your project and change your application `Output Type` from `Console Aplication` to `Windows Application`.

This will fix your issue.

Comment: Hehe, I'm feeling pretty dumb right now. Thanks heaps Quitin! :-D + 1